# In a while loop how do I go to the next cell that is empty. (I'm trying not to override existing data)

Tags: excel, vba

Ok so the thing is, I'm writing this for an Excel Sheet, and the problem i've run into is the loop doesn't check to see if the destination cell is empty or not.  So what i'm trying to do is check if the cell is empty if it is then do the existing paste.  if it's not then keep looking till it finds the first empty box....can someone help with this?

```
Dim x, z

Set a = Sheets("Working")
Set b = Sheets("Peer Review")
Set c = Sheets("Waiting to Push")
Set d = Sheets("Completed")
x = 1
z = 2

Do Until IsEmpty(a.Range("I" & z))
    If a.Range("I" & z) = "Peer" Then
        x = x + 1
        b.Rows(x).Value = a.Rows(z).Value
    Else
        If a.Range("I" & z) = "Waiting" Then
            x = x + 1
            c.Rows(x).Value = a.Rows(z).Value

        End If
    End If
    z = z + 1
Loop
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend to rewrite the code as follows:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub tmpSO()

Dim z As Long
Dim a As Worksheet, b As Worksheet, c As Worksheet, d As Worksheet

Set a = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Working")
Set b = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Peer Review")
Set c = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Waiting to Push")
Set d = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Completed")
z = 2

For z = a.Cells(a.Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
    If a.Cells(z, "I").Value2 <> vbNullString Then
        Select Case UCase(a.Cells(z, "I").Value2)
            Case "PEER"
                b.Rows(b.Cells(b.Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row + 1).Value2 = a.Rows(z).Value2
                a.Rows(z).Delete
            Case "WAITING"
                c.Rows(c.Cells(c.Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row + 1).Value2 = a.Rows(z).Value2
                a.Rows(z).Delete
            Case "COMPLETED"
                d.Rows(d.Cells(d.Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row + 1).Value2 = a.Rows(z).Value2
                a.Rows(z).Delete
            Case Else
                MsgBox "Unknown value " & a.Cells(z, "I").Value2 & " in row " & z & Chr(10) & "Skipping to next row..."
        End Select
    End If
Next z

End Sub
```

Changes:

1. Implement a `for ... next` instead of a `loop` is most of the time a better coding practice since a `loop` can potentially lead to an infinite loop and crash your Excel.
2. Using `select case` instead of multiple `if` clauses. This is not really much faster but simply better to read and understand.
3. I removed `x` because this would not always use the last row on each sheet. Instead `x` is incremented on each sheet and thus can lead to empty (in between) rows on all other sheets. Instead, the above code now checks column `I` for the last row on that sheet and then copies the row from sheet `a` over to the next available one.
4. The above code is now (no longer) case sensitive when checking for `peer` or `Peer` or `pEEr` in column `I`. I am guessing that this better suits your needs.
5. If an unknown value (other than `peer`, `waiting`, or `completed`) in column `I` is encountered then you get a message box telling you about it.
6. In accordance to your request (in the comments below) the above code now `deletes` any row which has been successfully copied over to another sheet. Yet, unrecognized values in column `I` cannot be copied over to any other sheet and (as such) stay on sheet `a` ("Working").

Note, that the above assumes that "empty" is defined as "there in nothing in the cell's formula. If you prefer you can also set it to "if the cell is showing no value" (instead). The difference is that if a cell contains a formula which results in "" then there is a formula in the cell but the value is currently (due to the formula) nothing.

Comment: hmmm ok and if I wanted it to remove the row it just copied? like say for example instead of copy paste, more of a cut and paste?

Comment: Then we have to rewrite to code a bit more. That's because if you delete a row then row 10 (for example) needs to be checked "again". Because it got cut out and row 11 is now row 10. So, as long as a cut & paste occurs one and the same row needs to be processed over and over again. Let me know if this is what you want and I'll rewrite the above code.

Comment: Yes please, a cut and paste would be ideal

Comment: Ok...however this wouldn't see a table as blank...even though the cell is blank...it would copy it but it wouldn't paste it into another table on another sheet...it would go to the end of the table then paste....is there some small portion of this that could be changed to allow this exception?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. But as it stands right now, a row is only processed if the cell in column `I` contains **something**. If the cell in column `I` contains nothing then the row is **not** cut but left (as is) on the sheet `a` ("Working"). Yet, if you wish to change that and also process rows where column `I` **evaluates** to nothing then there is another line in the code you should uncomment and use instead: `If a.Cells(z, "I").Value2 <> vbNullString Then`. I made a minor adjustment which might help (if I understood you correctly). Otherwise, you'll have to explain some more.

Comment: hahha ok let me explain abit better.  In excel the information is to transfer from one table that has fiters etc on it, to another....now it cuts it with no issues..however when it pastes it it pastes it under the blank table into the actual sheet...so it's not filterable...does that make a bit more sense?

Comment: No, unfortunately this doesn't make sense to me. Maybe if you were to edit your post above and include the current outcome and what you'd expect instead as screenshots?